# Does Signal R support media message sending in android?

Tags: android, signalr, chat

> Simple chat Through Signal R is working fine but i want to send images
>   or any type of file, but i didn't get any thing to do that. Can i do
>   that or not please guide me.?
>   i used this GitHub library.
>   [SignalR](https://github.com/ahmadaghazadeh/SignalRAndroid/tree/master/Src)

Answer (score 0):

```
Can i do that or not please guide me.
```

Yes, you can do that, but little more efforts are required. To achieve that you would be needing below steps

1) First you need a server where you upload a file. For this make upload file service to send byte data (Uploading byte data tutorials can be found over google)

2) Once you upload file via web service, on success it should return the path of the server and file name (where that was saved on server)

3) After getting the path send this path as simple message (As you are already sending simple text message with Signal R). And add additional property to differentiate between normal text message of media message.

4) on receiving side (second user whom you are chatting with) check if the message has that additional property(which you added in previous step). If additional property is found, use that URL or file path to download the image from server and save it locally

Hope that helps :)

Comment: i don't want to use web service separately to upload image . just like send_message method want a method to send image on runtime.

Comment: There is no method for this.